# Print specific worksheets in Excel, with different print areas and print setup using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, printing

I have a workbook with 6 different worksheets. This workbook needs to give the user the option to print 2 different sets of reports. Option 1 will print worksheets 1, 3 and 5 and Option 2 will print worksheets 2, 4 and 6. Each worksheet will require a different print range and print set up. I have approached it like this and wanted to know if this is best way to approach it (I'm sure there is a better/correct way of doing it).

```
Sub printingSheets()

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet
Dim Sh5 As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook

Set Sh1 = .Sheets(“Dataset1”)
Set Sh3 = .Sheets(“Dataset2”)
Set Sh5 = .Sheets(“Dataset3”)

‘Setting the print area

Sh1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$C$5"
Sh3.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$S$5"
Sh5.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$AA$7"

‘Setting up the print setup

Sh1.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
Sh3.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
Sh5.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3

‘Print

Array(Sh1, Sh3, Sh5).PrintOut Copies:=1

End Sub
```

And then I would write a separate macro for the other sheets.

Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: You could write a general sub that let you pass in worksheets, then loop through them, looking up the correct print area etc from somewhere else (or a collection defined in the sub).  But given the small number of sheets involved and the fact that the print areas and setup is hard coded separately for each of them anyway, I think your approach is fine.  Unless it may need to be extended in future?

Comment: Thanks @aucuparia Yeah I agree, for the amount of tabs i think I will just proceed with the above code. Thanks for giving it a look over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make separate subs for each functionality, and place "magic" numbers at the top, as constants, for easier maintenance

```
Option Explicit

Private Const WS_NAME   As String = "Dataset"
Private Const WS_ID     As String = "1 2 3 4 5 6"           'Dataset & #
Private Const WS_RANGE1 As String = "A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1"     'First print Cell
Private Const WS_RANGE2 As String = "C5 X1 S5 X1 AA7 X1"    'Last print Cell
Private Const WS_SIZE   As String = "9 9 9 9 8 9"           'xlPaperA4=9, xlPaperA3=8

Public Sub printWSset()

    setPrintInfo        'main setup and config

    printSet "1 3 5"    'easy to change, independent of Worksheet setup

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub printSet(ByRef wsIDs As String)
    Dim wsID As Variant

    If Len(wsIDs) > 0 Then
        For Each wsID In Split(wsIDs)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsID).PrintOut Copies:=1
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub setPrintInfo()
    Dim wsName As Variant, wsR1 As Variant, wsR2 As Variant, wsSz As Variant, i As Long

    wsName = Split(WS_ID)       'split string by default char (space); array base at 0
    wsR1 = Split(WS_RANGE1)
    wsR2 = Split(WS_RANGE2)
    wsSz = Split(WS_SIZE)

    For i = 0 To UBound(wsName)
        setInfo WS_NAME & wsName(i), wsR1(i), wsR2(i), Val(wsSz(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub setInfo(ByVal x As String, r1 As Variant, r2 As Variant, sz As Long)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x).PageSetup
        .PrintArea = r1 & ":" & r2
        .PaperSize = sz
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @paul bica, I'm really interested to get this work. When I ran it through it through the VBA and got back the Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch for the Public Sub setPrintInfo (). Is there something I should do prior running the code? Thanks

Comment: I fixed the type mismatch issue - changed r1 and r2 to Variants, and added Val() for  wsSz to send it as long. I tested and it seems to work but I don't have a printer setup (I'm not sure about `.PrintOut` and `.PaperSize = sz`)